# Swipe to confirm layout in Android

Tags: android

Helo,

Is their any library that supports the swipe to delete feature as implemented in gmail on Android, that also shows the undo button ? I saw this also on google io 2013, so i assumed this is natively supported by Android ? Is this so ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes there is but you need to slightly modify those based on your need:

https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss and this https://github.com/timroes/SwipeToDismissUndoList
and this https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview

Comment: thanks. But why have google implemented a feature that is not natively available ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no library i guess. But u can implement it by using DragListener and making the view's visibility to gone (make a custom view by extending it). And when you undo, set the Visibility to "Visible"

You can also use OnTouchListener and listen to the co-ordinates on which user performs drag & then perform your logic.